# ¿Cómo elimino este error 3730 en mi código de My SQL?

Tags: mysql

```sql
create table products( 
  id int not null auto_increment
  , name varchar(50) not null
  , created_by int not null
  , marca varchar(50) not null
  , primary key(id)
  , foreign key(created_by) references user (id) ); 
  rename table products to product; 
  insert into product (
  name
  , created_by
  , marca) 
  values 
  ('ipad',1,'apple')
  , ('iphone',1,'apple')
  , ('watch',2,'apple')
  , ('macbook',1,'apple')
  , ('imac',3,'apple')
  , ('ipad mini',3,'apple'); 

  select * from product; 
  select u.id
  , u.email
  , p.name 
  from 
  user u 
  left join product p on u.id=p.created_by; 

  select u.id
  , u.email
  , p.name 
  from user u right join product p on u.id=p.created_by; 
  
  select u.id
  , u.name
  , p.id
  , p.name from user u cross join product p; 
  
  select count(id)
  , marca 
  from product group by marca; 

  select count(p.id)
  , u.name 
  from product p left join user u on u.id = p.created_by group by p.created_by; 

  select count(p.id)
  , u.name 
  from product p left join user u on u.id = p.created_by group by p.created_by 
  having count(p.id) >= 2; 

  drop table product; 

  drop table animales; -- error drop table user;
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask]

Comment: Veo difícil que encuentres a alguien dispuesto a revisar un código sin formato (incluyendo indentación); pero es un buena oportunidad para que aprendas a hacerlo.

Comment: Ademas de indentar de forma correcta, Puedes compartir el mensaje de error que aparece como tal.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te falta es definir la tabla `user` e insertar al menos 3 registros:

```
CREATE TABLE `user`(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(63),
  email varchar(127)
  );
INSERT INTO user (name, email) VALUES
('u1','e1@email.com'),
('u2','e2@email.com'),
('u3','e3@email.com');
```

No he obtenido más errores ejecutando tu código, excepto la última línea porque la tabla `animales` tampoco existe